# Exponential moving averages of a time series with varying sampling

Tags: time-series

If I have a (financial) time series, and I sample it with two different periods, at 5 and at 60 minute intervals, can I create an exponential moving average on the 5 minute sampled data which is the same as an exponential moving average on the 60 minute sampled data?

Something like this:
e1 = EMA(a1) applied on sampled_data(60 min)
e2 = EMA(a2) applied on sampled_data(5 min)

a1 and a2 are the smoothing factors of the exponential moving average (the period)

Can I compute the a2 value for any a1 value, such that e1 = e2?

When I say that e1 = e2 I mean that if I graph the values of the EMA computed from 5 min data on top of the 60 min data chart and EMA, the two EMAs should be superposed. This means that in between two data points for EMA(60 min) there will be 60/5=12 data points for EMA(5 min).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trivial and non-helpful answer is "Yes, downsample your 5-minute data to 60-minute data."

More practically, without throwing out 90% of your data, the answer is generally "No, unless you get extremely lucky with sampling your five-minute data."  You should get an answer that's *close* (and under most noise models I suspect they'll be equal in expectation) just by rescaling your smooth by a factor of 12, but any source of randomness in your data is going to cause some difference in the two curves on a point-by-point basis.